# who to work AES_DECRYPT in mysql?

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

i use from `AES_ENCRYPT(...)` in mysql for encrypte a column of table but when i use from `AES_DECRYPT` for decrypte, result is null.

please help me. thanks.

code for encrypt:

```
UPDATE TBL_USERS SET PASSWORD = AES_ENCRYPT(PASSWORD , '123456');
```

code for decrypte:

```
SELECT CAST(aes_decrypt(PASSWORD,'123456') AS CHAR) FROM TBL_USERS
```

[image]

Comment: It must never be possible to retrieve a password.  You need to _hash_ passwords using PBKDFv2 or bcrypt.

Answer (score 0):

Password must be a string 'PASSWORD'. Password without quotes is field name.

```
UPDATE TBL_USERS SET PASSWORD = AES_ENCRYPT('PASSWORD' , '123456');
```

Try AES_DECRYPT witout CAST function:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(PASSWORD,'123456') FROM TBL_USERS
```